# Error opening serial port '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem'. (Port busy)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, uploading

I’m sorry if I sound ignorant and naive, but I’m brand new to Arduino;  very keen, but know very little.

I started with a Sainsmart Arduino Uno clone board.  I downloaded the software, which opened OK (or at least seemed to), but the Serial Monitor kept telling me that there was a communication error, and a yellow light kept flashing on the Sainsmart board.

I got hold of a genuine Arduino (from Jameco), uninstalled everything Arduino, and started again from scratch.

Now I get the message:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
Error opening serial port '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem'. (Port busy)
  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

And after enabling the verbose output, got:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
Error opening serial port '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem'. (Port busy)
```

Tried again, and:

```
Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
Error opening serial port '/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem'. (Port busy)
```

I’m using a MacBook Pro, using Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Why are you trying to communicate with a bluetooth modem when the Arduino plugs in through USB?

Comment: Is there a `/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem`? @Majenko that's an OSX thing. I have the same thing here on my Mac.

Comment: @Gerben I know what it is - I am just wondering why the OP is trying to use it.  It's the equivalent to /dev/rfcomm* on Linux.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong port to me. It shouldn't be on the Bluetooth-Modem port.

Comment: The Bluetooth Modem port is obviously wrong, but it's there on just about every Mac, so people seem to choose it in desperation when their Arduino (or more commonly clone) is not recognized.  Needless to say it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You are not selecting the correct port to upload to - hence the strange message about the Bluetooth modem. Start by unplugging your Uno and running Arduino. Select Tools -> Port from the menu bar. You should see a list of options. Now plug in your Uno and do the same again. You should see an extra port listed now - this will be the Uno. Select it. You will need to check this every time you connect a board.

Also, before you click Upload, make sure you have Arduino Uno selected under Tools -> Board in the menu bar.